# C++ 11db error when trying to quit the program in xcode. beginner level

Tags: c++, xcode, do-while

I am in the begining steps to answer a Lottery HW problem, however, when I call the getLottoPicks function it throws off the program with an 11db error. So when the program first runs and you exit with 'q' or 'Q' it works, but if the user goes thru the program once and then tries to quit I get the 11db error. I tried sticking cin.ignore() in all sorts of places but that didn't help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void menu();
int getLottoPicks(int[], int);

int main()
{
    char choice;
    const int SIZE = 6;
    int UserTicket[SIZE];
    int WinningNums[SIZE];
    string name;

    do
    {
        menu();
        cin  >> choice;
        cout << endl;
        cin.ignore();

        switch (choice)
        {
            case '1':
                cout << "Please enter your name: ";
                getline(cin, name);

                getLottoPicks(UserTicket,SIZE);

                for(int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)
                {
                    cout << UserTicket[i];
                    cout << ", ";
                }
                cout << endl <<endl;
                break;
            case 'q':
            case 'Q':
                cout << "You have chosen to quit the program. Thank you for using!\n";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalide Selection.\n";
                break;
        }

    }while (choice != 'q' && choice != 'Q');

    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    cout << "1) Play Lotto\n";
    cout << "q) Quit Program\n";
    cout << "Please make a selection: \n";
}

int getLottoPicks(int nums[], int size)
{
    cout << "Please enter your 7 lotto number picks between 1 and 40.\n";

    for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please pick #" << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin  >> nums[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
    return nums[0], nums[1], nums[2], nums[3], nums[4], nums[5], nums[6];
}
```

/* Here is a run thru of the program
1) Play Lotto
q) Quit Program
Please make a selection: 
1

Please enter your name: asdf
Please enter your 7 lotto number picks between 1 and 40.
Please pick #1: 1

Please pick #2: 1

Please pick #3: 1

Please pick #4: 1

Please pick #5: 1

Please pick #6: 1

Please pick #7: 1

1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,

1) Play Lotto
q) Quit Program
Please make a selection: 
q

You have chosen to quit the program. Thank you for using!
(11db) <----- this is what I am getting in green color. and the program doesn't quit until i manually close it with Cmd .
*/

Comment: `11db error` what is that? If there is an error message please edit your question post the exact text of the error message.

Comment: It just says 11db and doesnt end the program. a side tab opens in x-code with libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x7fff65d232bc <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
    0x7fff65d232c1 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x7fff65d232c4 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x7fff65d232c6 <+10>: jae    0x7fff65d232d0            ; <+20>
    0x7fff65d232c8 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff65d232cb <+15>: jmp    0x7fff65d1d457            ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7fff65d232d0 <+20>: retq

Comment: I think it is something to do with the function call in switch case 1: When I comment that out the program quits successfully

Comment: Thank You for adding the additional context. I don't use `xcode` and in the 25 to 30 years I have programmed in c++ I have not seen an error code referred as 11db error..

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++)` is a bug. This is called and off by 1 error. You need `i < SIZE` instead if `i <= SIZE`. Same bug here: `for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++)`. Note that valid indices for an array are 0 .. SIZE - 1

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I have 25-30 days in c++ haha. I am not sure whats causing it, first time I got it too. I've emailed my professor and will come back if i figure it out and let you guys know.

Comment: OH! that worked, I am no longer getting that error. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the function `getLottoPicks`.

First to point a design problem: you are somehow calling this function to get 7 inputs from the user but you are mistakenly returning 7 elements from the parameter `nums` (which in your case is causing the function to access the 7th element from an array that only contains 6 elements). Besides that you are already getting the values by storing the them in the `nums` parameter. Change the `getLottoPicks` return type to `void` and delete the `return nums[0], nums[1], nums[2], nums[3], nums[4], nums[5], nums[6];` line.

Secondly you are using the condition to exit the for loops wrong. Arrays in C++ are accessed by indexes starting with 0. When you state the exit condition to a for loop to exit when the iterator becomes <= than the array size, you are actually making the code to cause a stack overflow problem when execute (it will write to the array variable beyond its boundaries). In the case of your code, change the `<=` operator to `<` in the for loop inside the `getLottoPicks`.

Comment: Awesome thank you! so doing <= made it return 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 total 7 nums instead of the 6 which caused the error

Comment: It is not "returning" anything inside the `for loop`. However if I understood you right, yes, the code is actually acessing the nums[6] element, which is actually the 7th element of an array that only have 6 elements.

Comment: Perfect! thanks again. Ive changed const int SIZE = 7 and changed both for loops to for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) as well as changing the function to void and removing the return line.

Comment: Glad I could help. If it fixed your problem please consider accepting my answer to your question.

Comment: Oh cool didn't know that was an option, first timer here. Thanks again, also too drescherjm and duskwuff thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`(lldb)` is the command prompt for the [LLDB](https://lldb.llvm.org/) debugger, not an error code. Your program has crashed, probably because you're loading 7 elements into an array of size 6.